# Router sendind to DDNS the gateway ip not the router ip

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, ddns

I have a router TP-LINK model TL-WR949N v.6 connected by PPPoE in the WAN port. I tried to register a Dynamic DNS in the router and the router connected normally to my NO-IP DDNS. But the IP of the DDNS is the router's WAN gateway ip and not the external router's ip. So i can't connect remotely to my router by DDNS because the ip is wrong. If i get the router ip i can manage it remotely normally, but the ip changes, so i need the DDNS working.

Someone can help me?

Thank you,
William

Comment: You do not connect remotely to the router by IP, but by your NO-IP domain-name. That way your IP is always correct. That is the main reason for using DDNS.

Comment: No, i enter phisically in a LAN network so i enter in the router and get it's ip, so i can go anywhere in the world and connect by it ip. But, i can't get the ip by my DDNS because the ip sent by my router to the NO-IP domain is the wan gateway ip, and not the external router ip.